# How to check if value is in array on CanCanCan hash of conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, cancancan

I have three model classes: `PatientBoard`, `Medication` and `Customer`, which relates to each other like the following:

**PatientBoard**

```
associations do 
      has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
      has_many :medications
end
```

**Medication**

```
associations do 
      belongs_to :patient_board
end
```

**Customer**

```
associations do 
      has_many :patient_boards
end
```

Due to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, my patient_board object looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5e160f235eb3607d57f59341"), 
  name: "test",
  customer_ids: [ObjectId("5db1e6f45eb36059a4d98e7f")]
}
```

Where the ids from all the customers who have access to that patient board will be inside the customer_ids array.

**The problem**

When trying to set the permissions to the user, I did it like the following for the `PatientBoard`:

```
can :manage, PatientBoard do |pb|
    pb.customer_ids.include? user.id
end
```

It works for the most part. But the `create` method still wouldn't work, so I had to insert the following line too:

```
can :create, PatientBoard
```

Now it works normally, but when I tried to do the same for the `Medication` it didn't work:

```
can :manage, Medication do |m|
    m.patient_board.customer_ids.include? user.id
end
```

It throws this error message:

> The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition. The SQL cannot be determined for :index Medication

So I tried doing it like this:

```
can :manage, Medication, patient_board: { customers: { id: user.id } }
```

That way the error message isn't shown anymore, but neither are the medications. And when trying to create a new medication it throws that error:

> undefined method `matches?' for #PatientBoard:0x007f663c38d0e8 Did you mean? _matches? matcher

Which I think that makes sense, since its trying to compare an String value (`user.id`) to an array value (`customer_ids`)

**In resume**

How can I check if the `user.id` is in the `customer_ids` array using the hash of conditions of the CanCanCan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i managed to solve the problem after checking the [issue #345](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/345) on the CanCan github.

Apparently, i had to provide an sql query to match the medications, so i did it like this:

```
can [:manage], [Medication], ["#{user.id} in ( select customer_ids from patient_board where id = medications.patient_board.id ) )"] do |t|
   t.patient_board.customer_ids.include? user.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `include?` is triggering a sql query inside the `can` block. Try converting the customer_ids to an array:

```rb
can :manage, Medication do |m|
  m.patient_board.customer_ids.to_a.include? user.id
end
```